# Как увеличить форму в WindowsForm, так что бы было видно панель управления , НО при этом FormBorderStyle = NONE;

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Как увеличить форму в WindowsForm, так что бы было видно панель управления , НО при этом FormBorderStyle = NONE;

Comment: Быть может панель задач? Или вы про кнопки в заголовке окна?

Comment: Что за панель управления? При FormBorderStyle = NONE заголовок формы не отображается, т.к. формально является частью этого самого бордера. Если хотите кнопки из заголовка - рисуйте их самостоятельно или отказывайтесь от безрамоного окна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так понял, нужно распахнуть форму на всё окно, не закрывая при этом TaskBar.

```
FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
MaximizedBounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```